# combobox itemsource in a datagrid depends on the selecteditem of another combobox in the same datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a combobox inside a datagrid, it can be bind with any of two lists depending on a selected value of another combobox in the same datagrid.

**i.e:** if column one in the datagrid is a combobox(**combobox1**) and it is bind with **List1** of values:

**l1Value1**

**l1Value2**

**l1Value3**

and Column two in the datagrid is also a combobox(**combobox2**) and it is bind (by default) with **list2** of values:

**l2Value1**

**l2Value2**

**l3VAlue3**

If in a certain row in the datagrid, the user changed the selection of **Combobox1** to **l1Value3**,
**combobox2** of this row, will be binded to **list3** of values:

**l3Value1**

**l3Value2**

**l3Value3**

if the choice of **combobox1** is changed to any value except **l1Value3**, **combobox2** will be bind to **list2**

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you ever had a solution to this problem? 
Thanks.